# Folder Name contains # symbol but thumbnails are not displaying

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, thumbnails

Hi I have developed an apps in Windows Phone 8, which download the images from the server to the phone, And each and every folder is the `pictures` and the `thumbnails` are displaying, without any problem. But if there is a folder with `"#"` symbol like `Fold#er`, then inside the folder all the images are displyed, but the thumbnails are not displayed, it is empty.

I have debugged the code and there is no issue, no exception. Even in the server I have tested it is working fine with Thumbnails and pictures.

Any idea why is `#` symbol creating this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a lot of research I found the solution,  thanks to @Blazes for the suggestions, but it was different issue. In my application whenever it found any special character like #, ^,<, > etc it just truncate the string until that and the worst part is it was not throwing any error/ exception. Now I have used

```
string escapeStr = Uri.EscapeDataString(filepath);
```

This line was enough to solve the problem, but sometimes the entire string needs to be escape encoding

like suppose you have a string which is like

`string request = "Username" + uname + "Password" +Pwd + "Filepath" + filepath;`

then in this case

`string unamestr = Uri.EscapeDataString(uname);`

`string Pwdstr = Uri.EscapeDataString(Pwd );`

will not help, because you are dealing with unicode character. So in that case the entire string need to be encode like this

`string request = Uri.EscapeDataString("Username" + uname + "Password" +Pwd + "Filepath" + filepath);`

This is the solution I found through trial / error method and from SO.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The hash (#) is a URL anchor.  It sounds like you need to URL encode your paths.  E.g. `Fold%23er`

Comment: then how shall I resolve this? Shall I change the # to %23? like `if (imgTinyThumbnail.FilePath.Contains("#"))
      {
        imgTinyThumbnail.FilePath.Replace(("#", "%23");
      }`